# Android download image from shorturl

Tags: android, facebook, download, short-url

I'm trying to download an Image from [this](https://graph.facebook.com/1511855235783268/picture) given short-url/redirect from facebook, but in my case it doesnt work -  heres my code:

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Bitmap btm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        is.close();
        return btm;
    }catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.v(Constants.LOG_TAG, "[Error] " + e + ": " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v(Constants.LOG_TAG, "[Error] " + e + ": " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

it also works fine if I uses [the long link](https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfl1/t31.0-8/s720x720/12493710_1511855235783268_1190862665117986925_o.jpg), but i need to get this pic from the shorten one. Does anybody know how to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Is your short url broken?

Comment: no, why should it be broken?

Comment: I don't know, from what it sounds like, you're saying it works with the long url but not the short one, so I thought it could be broken

Comment: Maybe it's because of an http redirect

Comment: yeah and just this redirect is my problem :/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use http instead:

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Or try to use one of following library, example:

Android Universal Image Loader: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader 
ion: https://github.com/koush/ion 
Glide: https://github.com/bumptech/glide